# how can I loop for every GerritInfo['GerritInfo']

Tags: python

I have the following code where I want to loop over every GerritInfo['GerritInfo'][0...n] and add logic based on that,currently am doing it only for first item,i.e.,
GerritInfo['GerritInfo'][0] ,how can loop for every GerritInfo['GerritInfo'] assuming we dont know how many items are in GerritInfo['GerritInfo']

```
#!/usr/bin/python
GerritInfo = {'Assignee': 'username', 'RCAInfo': 'Provided', 'PLProductLine': 'LNX.LA.0.0', 'GerritInfo': [{'Url': 'https://review-android.company.com/761190', 'Status': 'MERGED', 'kw_ran': 'kw running', 'Info': 'ALREADY INTEGRATED', 'lookahead_ran': 'lookahead running'}, {'Url': 'https://review-android.company.com/777849', 'Status': 'NEW', 'kw_ran': 'kw did not run', 'Info': 'Available', 'lookahead_ran': 'lookahead running'}], 'CRId': '<a href="http://prism/CR/664310">664310</a>', 'CRStatus': 'Fix', 'RNotesStatus': 'Yes', 'TargetName': 'MSM8916', 'IsDevComplete': 'True'}


if (('Not Provided' in GerritInfo['GerritInfo'][0]['Url'] or 'Wrong Gerrit Provided' in GerritInfo['GerritInfo'][0]['Url']) or ('NEW' in GerritInfo['GerritInfo'][0]['Status'] or 'ABANDONED' in GerritInfo['GerritInfo'][0]['Status'] or 'Yes' not in GerritInfo['RNotesStatus'] or 'Provided' not in GerritInfo['RCAInfo'] or 'False' in str(GerritInfo['IsDevComplete']))):
    print "Inside if"
else:
    print "in else"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in GerritInfo['GerritInfo'] is just a list, so you can loop over it with the normal idiom.

```
for gerrit in GerritInfo['GerritInfo']:
    print gerrit
```

Edit:
Just wrap your existing logic in the for loop.  For example

```
for gerrit in GerritInfo['GerritInfo']:
    if (('Not Provided' in gerrit['Url'] or 'Wrong Gerrit..))
        print "inside if"
```

Comment: how to change the existing if loop withouth adding a for loop